# Output doesn't display all utf-8 correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, io

I'm writing a website scraper (using lxml and py3k on Windows 8) for http://www.delfi.lt - the goal is to output certain information to a .txt file.  Obviously ASCII can't work as an encoding due to the website being in Lithuanian, so I attempt to print it in UTF-8.  However, not all of the non-ASCII characters are being printed out to the file correctly.

An example of this is where I get `DELFI Å½inios > Dienos naujienos > UÅ¾sienyje` as opposed to `DELFI Žinios > Dienos naujienos > Užsienyje`.

Here is as far as I've gotten with the scraper:

```
from lxml import html
import sys

# Takes in command line input, namely the URL of the story and (optionally) the name of the CSV file that will store all of the data
# Outputs a list consisting of two strings, the first will be the URL, and the second will be the name if given, otherwise it'll be an empty string
def accept_user_input():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 or len(sys.argv) > 3:
        raise type('IncorrectNumberOfArgumentsException', (Exception,), {})('Should have at least one, up till two, arguments.')
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        return [sys.argv[1], '']
    else:
        return sys.argv[1:]

def main():
    url, name = accept_user_input()
    page = html.parse(url)

    title = page.find('//h1[@itemprop="headline"]')
    category = page.findall('//span[@itemprop="title"]')

    with open('output.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as f:
        f.write((title.text) + "\n")
        f.write(' > '.join([x.text for x in category]) + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

An example run: `python scraper.py http://www.delfi.lt/news/daily/world/ukraina-separatistai-siauteja-o-turcynovas-atnaujina-mobilizacija.d?id=64678799` results in a file called `output.txt` containing

```
Ukraina: separatistai siautÄja, O. TurÄynovas atnaujina mobilizacijÄ
DELFI Å½inios > Dienos naujienos > UÅ¾sienyje
```

as opposed to

```
Ukraina: separatistai siautÄja, O. TurÄynovas atnaujina mobilizacijÄ
DELFI Žinios > Dienos naujienos > Užsienyje
```

How do I make the script output all of the text correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using requests and beautifulSoup and letting requests handle the encoding using `.content` works for me :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    url, name = "http://www.delfi.lt/news/daily/world/ukraina-separatistai-siauteja-o-turcynovas-atnaujina-mobilizacija.d?id=64678799","foo.csv"
    r = requests.get(url)

    page = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

    title = page.find("h1",{"itemprop":"headline"})
    category = page.find_all("span",{"itemprop":"title"})
    print(title)
    with open('output.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as f:
        f.write((title.text) + "\n")
        f.write(' > '.join([x.text for x in category]) + '\n')
```

Output:

```
Ukraina: separatistai siautėja, O. Turčynovas atnaujina mobilizacijąnaujausi susirėmimų vaizdo įrašai
DELFI Žinios > Dienos naujienos > Užsienyje
```

Changing the parser  encoding also works:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
page = html.parse(url,parser)
```

So change your code to the following :

```
from lxml import html,etree
import sys

# Takes in command line input, namely the URL of the story and (optionally) the name of the CSV file that will store all of the data
# Outputs a list consisting of two strings, the first will be the URL, and the second will be the name if given, otherwise it'll be an empty string
def accept_user_input():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 or len(sys.argv) > 3:
        raise type('IncorrectNumberOfArgumentsException', (Exception,), {})('Should have at least one, up till two, arguments.')
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        return [sys.argv[1], '']
    else:
        return sys.argv[1:]

def main():
    parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
    page = html.parse(url,parser))

    title = page.find('//h1[@itemprop="headline"]')
    category = page.findall('//span[@itemprop="title"]')

    with open('output.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='w') as f:
        f.write((title.text) + "\n")
        f.write(' > '.join([x.text for x in category]) + '\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```